# Jquery Param only adding first pair to new url string

Tags: jquery, parameters

On submit I am attempting to add to the url the key value pairs from a form that is being filled out. I understand how to get the values and I am getting the correct response back when I do an alert but for some reason when I attempt to add the new query string values to the url it only adds the first value in the array. Here is what I have for my code. Any help would be great.

```
var Url = $('#step1').attr('action');
var FirstName = $('input#FirstName').val();
var LastName = $('input#LastName').val();
var EmailAddress = $('input#EmailAddress').val();
var params = {'lastname':LastName, 'firstname':FirstName, 'emailaddress':EmailAddress};
var Nurl = Url+'?'+jQuery.param(params);
alert(jQuery.param(params));
$('#step1').attr('action', Nurl);
theForm.submit();
```

Unfortunately, with the system that I am using I cannot do a GET request so this jquery is adding the query strings to the success page which is at the end of the url. I need it to add all three query parameters but right now it is only adding the first one in the list.

Comment: I don't get this part _I attempt to add the new query string values to the url it only adds the first value in the array_. What url you refer to?

Comment: After `$('#step1').attr('action', Nurl);` try `alert($('#step1').attr('action'))` and see if you are actually setting the action attribute appropriately. Also, way easier to just `window.location.href = Nurl`

Comment: THis is what I am referring to

var Nurl = Url+'?'+jQuery.param(params);

the current action url of the form is stored in the Url variable then I am adding to that with the line above.

Comment: I know the url is working as it goes to the correct page but it only adds the first key value pair of the array instead of all three

Comment: @psalmody - I added the attr('action') and it is giving me the correct url but when the form submits and goes to the success page it is dropping the last two query parameters for some reason.

Comment: Why not change to window.location.href?

Comment: The form is being submitted via post. I am attempting to add query strings to the success url which is also a query string of the form action url. I am not just replacing the window url I am submitting the post form request. If I was only adding one query string it would be working perfectly but I am attempting to add three to the success url that is where I am confused as to why it is dropping the last two parameters

Comment: I think we need to see more on how the action script is handling the POST request and understand more why you need to append query parameters. As in, what makes it so you can't just add those as POST parameters and then make your action script add them to the URL (if really necessary) when you get there.